# using Google Guice GraphViz extension and private modules

Tags: java, dependency-injection, visualization, guice

I have simple private module:

```
public class SomePrivateModule extends PrivateModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(SomeInterface.class).
        annotatedWith(SomeAnotation.class).
        to(SomeClass.class);

        expose(SomeInterface.class).annotatedWith(SomeAnotation.class);


        bind(String.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("some_name")).toInstance("foofoo");
    }
}
```

I using this module in another module using `install(new SomePrivateModule)`. unfortunately on dependencies graph I get `"k_26662236"` in circle instead of `@SomeAnotation SomeInterface` in rectangle  and dependencies for `SomeClass`.

When I changing `SomePrivateModule` to extend `AbstractModule` instead of `PrivateModule` everything works fine.

Is it bug in Guice or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately graphing private modules isn't yet implemented.